# Watermark image and get image url

Tags: php, image, watermark

My code working good but one problem, i can't get image url, only i get site url.
My need this example url: `http://example.com/image.png` with watermark.
I wants to get direct watermark image url on here `<img src="http://example.com/image.png"/>`

Code:

```
<?php
$logo = 'http://www.slatecube.com/images/play-btn.png';
$img = 'http://i.imgur.com/GMjqTR7.jpg';
// Load the image where the logo will be embeded into
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);

// Load the logo image
$logoImage = imagecreatefrompng("$logo");
imagealphablending($logoImage, true);

// Get dimensions
$imageWidth=imagesx($image);
$imageHeight=imagesy($image);

$logoWidth=imagesx($logoImage);
$logoHeight=imagesy($logoImage);     

// Paste the logo
imagecopy(
// destination
$image, 
// source
$logoImage, 
// destination x and y 
($imageWidth-$logoWidth)/2, ($imageHeight-$logoHeight)/2,    
// source x and y
 0, 0,
// width and height of the area of the source to copy
$logoWidth, $logoHeight);

// Set type of image and send the output
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($image);

// Release memory
imageDestroy($image);
imageDestroy($imageLogo); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .htaccess for this. .htaccess will change route behaviors. When you call an image it will be actually a php file. Here is an example.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jp?g|png))$ img.php?imageName=$1 [NC]
```

a couple change for your code...

```
<?php
    $logo = 'ico.png';

    // I used a folder for images here
    $img = 'images/' . $_GET['imageName']; // it's a classic GET var

    //... after these changes add your code...
```